# HTML image is not displayed

Tags: html

My picture is not displayed. I've tried several browsers and different image formats. Unfortunately it doesn't always show up for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en ">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
        <img scr = "image.png">
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do the browser developer tools tell you?

Comment: I don't see the image in the browser developer tools either.

Comment: It's `src` not `scr`. This also assumes that your image and HTML file are in the same folder

Comment: The problem is that the image source cannot be located. Kindly check the `img src` attribute.

Comment: I am not sure why the down votes, the poster has a problem, shown their code, and suggested at what they have tried.  Their issue is a typo, I don't see the issue with the question

Comment: @JamieA An issue with a typo is reason to close a question as has happened.

Comment: thanks @Rob, I didn't realise that was a valid close reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your body tag
and the image needs a src attribute, not scr https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
<html lang="en ">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="image.png">
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `scr` to `src` in the img tag.

Also put it properly inside a body tag.

Something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <img src="image.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```